# Setting up a spreadsheet to analyze data on a week by week basis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I was hoping someone think of a logical/straightforward way of setting something up.

So every week at work I'm given a weekly report that displays the "Passed" percentages of a series of 90 questions on a test that is given to employees. The questions are always the same, but of course the Passed results are going to be different week to week. I need to compare the results of these percentages, so for example I need to be able to say "There was a 70% improvement on question 50 this past week". Pretty simple, but I'm stumped trying to think of a way to do easily do this.

I've tried a couple of different ways so far, but the best seems to be to create a table, list the questions, and a column displaying the Passed Percentage, where the header title is the date.

For instance:

```
+-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
|       Question        | 11/20/15 | 11/30/15 | 12/7/15 |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
| 1. Sample question 1  | 98%      | 92%      | 87%     |
| 2. Sample question 2  | 72%      | 83%      | 95%     |
| 3. Sample question 3  | 76%      | 91%      | 23%     |
| 4. Sample question 4  | 82%      | 66%      | 78%     |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

This has worked for me so far, but is kind of limited. Is there a better way to set something up that would allow me to forecast data, and compare data on a week by week, month by month, year by year basis?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your willingness to try some VBA (you can find examples to do most things online)

- Create a master spreadsheet to hold your data
- Write an import VBA function which imports the data from whatever file you are given every week
- Pivot tables are your friend. In addition to the link below, you should be able to find other examples online for categorizing data by timescale.

There's an older post on superuser which talks about using a pivotgrid to categorise by week: [How can I summarize my data by week?](https://superuser.com/questions/451576/how-can-i-summarize-my-data-by-week)

Comment: You're trying to answer a question that is pretty broad, which is difficult to do well in this format.  Just suggesting some general approaches isn't great as an answer because it isn't really a solution.  If the OP knew enough to make use of the suggestions, the question would have been a lot more specific.  These kinds of helpful suggestions are better done in a comment, which requires a little more rep.  Even though you're trying to help, you might find that this kind of answer attracts downvotes (no good deed goes unpunished).  :-)

Comment: Fair points - thanks. I guess if someone asked me this question at work, I'd try and guide them to finding the answer, rather than 'doing the work'

Comment: I appreciate the help! Sorry I was so vague in my post, but I was just unsure how to get something like this up and running.

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide some more specifics and I can try for a more specific answer? I.e. what format do you get the data i and even, a sample of the input?